# Container row space between col

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a container with several rows. And in each row I have several columns. 
I would like to increase the space between each column

```
<div class="main" style="margin-bottom:0px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 card ">
        Colonne 1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 card">
        Colonne 2
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 card">
        Colonne 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where's your CSS? What have you actually tried to accomplish this? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I didn’t try to find a solution because I just can’t find a way

Comment: you needed to play a bit more with bootstrap and read the docs a bit more too. look at spacing and grid utilities and find col and m-... classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card-deck text-center mb-5">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
      <hr class="w-50">
      <p class="text-left ml-3 mt-3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
      <hr class="w-50">
      <p class="text-left ml-3 mt-3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">test</h5>
      <hr class="w-50">
      <p class="text-left ml-3 mt-3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used this with cards, I think this what you're looking for. 
Keep me updated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

instead usind col-x while you want the same width, you may only use col and they will span the row with an equal width and let you add horizontal margins .

example

```css
.card {
  border: solid;/* to show where they are*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="main" style="margin-bottom:0px">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col  card mx-1 ">
            Colonne 1
          </div>

          <div class="col card mx-1">
            Colonne 2
          </div>

          <div class="col  card mx-1">
            Colonne 3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
```

ressources :

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/
>
> - t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
> - b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
> - l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
> - r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
> - x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
> - y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
> - blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

which is the reason of the `mx-1` class added

---

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
>    where you can find `col` class which is used to auto-size the columns , if all box receive the col class, they should be of equal width.

Comment: This solution works but if I put in mobile mode, the page is no longer responsive. In mobile mode, blocks must be placed below each other

Comment: you still can use the col-lg or col-sm class aside to keep it responsive the way you want., else at the worst, make your own break point via a mediaquerie . this shows you the basic to achieve your goal, else there is is not much choices left by bootstrap , just use regular class and forget about the gutter/gap in between ;)

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. If I understand correctly for 3 columns with space, I cannot use col-md4. I wanted to use this to have 3 equal columns in terms of width

Comment: Yes this is it,  if you set a number, bootstrap will fill a flex-basis value set in % .  Be curious , look at the css file  to find out how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I would like to add a line with 2 columns. The first column would be exactly the size of the first 2 columns of the first row. And the 2nd column the size of the 3rd column of the first row

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I want except it’s not beacons hr me

Comment: This solution works for 3 equal columns. But for example I want 2 columns on my first line size 8 and. How to increase the space

Comment: @totot You should make a new question for clarity with the code you want to use.(ex. instead  hr, it can be any tag , even pseudo.) Trick here pas using the flex values.

Comment: I have submitted a question that brings together the 2 cases I want on my various pages

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS margin property.

```
.card {
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

Working example

```css
.card {
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="main" style="margin-bottom:0px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-4 card ">
        Colonne 1
      </div>

      <div class="col col-md-4 card">
        Colonne 2
      </div>

      <div class="col col-md-4 card">
        Colonne 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: This solution just adds margin to the top and bottom. It doesn't create space between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns have no space between. 
Make another div inside by default column 4 has 15px padding which means if you make div inside it will leave space on both left and right side.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="inner">
     Your Content Here
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit you answer and include the css as a code sample.